# PCIe Video Card disabled after latest Catalina update?

Tags: catalina, gpu

Am I crazy or Catalina update disabled my PCIe Video Card (which is in my case Radeon Pro 560X) and it's using the integrated Intel UHD Graphics 630 as a main one?

After the update I’m experiencing strange lags occasionally, just like when u experience the FPS drop in games and it freezes for a fraction of a second...

**UPDATE**

Solution is [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io/). Just install it and you will have the option to choose which mode you would like to use. **Integrated Only**, **Discrete Only** and **Dynamic Switching**.

Comment: Can you check using [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io) and a GPU-heavy task such as [gputest](https://www.geeks3d.com/gputest/)?

Comment: @Allan The Radeon Pro 560X is only available in the 2018/2019 MacBook Pro 15" and 2019 iMac 21.5"

Comment: @Allan Not sure what you're trying to show me... that just shows that is is available in the 2018 tMBP 15", like I said. My main point is that it's not in a Mac Pro or an eGPU unless they happen to have a strange dev board.

Comment: @JMY1000 [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io/) helps! Now I can switch between 3 modes, _Integrated Only_, _Discrete Only_ and _Dynamic Switching_. It seems that Catalina update switched it to _Dynamic Switching_, however, _Discrete Only_ gives much smoother experience. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Go ahead and post that as an answer and mark it as accepted when you get the chance.